# How to get working button animation with built-in progress bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I need to get working button with progress bar [like here](http://lab.hakim.se/ladda/). I have set up resources, js binding but for some reason button is not acting as in the example. How to fix it?

My code:

```
<button class="progress-button ladda-button" data-color="mint" data-style="expand-right" data-size="xl" name="sendRequest"> <span class="ladda-label">Submit</span>
 <span class="ladda-spinner"></span>

    <div class="ladda-progress" style="width: 160px;"></div>
</button>

Ladda.bind('.ladda-button .progress-button button', {
    callback: function (instance) {
        var progress = 0;
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            progress = Math.min(progress + Math.random() * 0.1, 1);
            instance.setProgress(progress);

            if (progress === 1) {
                instance.stop();
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RCola/4p2jke75/

**UPDATE:**

I was following tutorial but still can find what is wrong with my jsfiddle code. How to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example it should be helpful [Example!](http://www.codersgrid.com/2013/06/09/ladda-js-loading-indicators-for-buttons/)